# How to structure a Firebase database for a static list?

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

What is the best way to structure a database in Firebase for the following scenario:

I am building an app that has the very basic functions of Yelp (lists businesses based on a chosen city).

I need to store many pieces of information (address, hours, e-mails, etc.) for the individual businesses. I also need to make sure I have a way to identify each business uniquely- my solution was to use the business phone number or e-mail.

Since search queries are conducted by city I thought the best way to structure my data tree would be:

```
Cities
  Phone
    Business Name
    City
    Contact Name
    Contact E-Mail
    E-Mail
```

Am I totally off base here regarding the use of proper NoSQL/Firebase data structure or am I on the right track? If I am not, how can I better improve the data tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That structure is probably fine, though I'd recommend using a more stable unique key (emails and phone numbers can change). I'd recommend a structure something like:

```
/businesses/{cityId}/{businessId}
  name
  phone
  contactName
  contactEmail
  email
```

Where `cityId` might be just a URL-friendly city name like `sf` or `nyc`. The primary challenge of structuring data for the Firebase Realtime Database is that you can only query on one property at a time, so you need to make sure that much of your data segmentation is enforced through path structure (this is why you wouldn't want `city` as a property of the business).

Comment: This answered my question but if I may ask a more advanced question: How would I best structure the data if I were using Geolocation data (e.g. querying database for nearest 10 businesses from current location)?

Comment: You'd want to take a look at [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire) for that. :)